# AppDynamics - Disable SqlIntegrity Constraint Violation Exception events for a specific DB2 table

Tags: db2-luw, appdynamics

My customer is using AppDynamics to monitor a DB2 database used internally by IBM Business Automation Workflow (IBM BAW).  BAW causes an SQL exception which can be safely ingored -
SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803,SQLSTATE=23505,
SQLERRMC=1;BT541BP1.BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB,DRIVER=4.32.28

This SQL exception is reported by AppDynamics.  The customer wants stop the reporting of these events.
Is it possible to turn off monitoring for this type of event on this specific table - BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB ?

I think the following link might be relevant:
https://docs.appdynamics.com/appd/4.5.x/en/appdynamics-essentials/alert-and-respond/configure-health-rules

I don't have direct access to AppDynamics, so I haven't been able to experiment with the system.
The error with code 23505 is thrown when trying to insert a row that would violate a unique index or primary key. I can't modify the design of the application (in this case IBM BAW).

Answer (score 0):

The IBM BAW product is working as designed. The SqlIntegrity Constraint Violation Exception can be safely ignored.  The solution was to set up a message filter within AppDynamics that looks specifically for the message:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-803,SQLSTATE=23505, SQLERRMC=1;BT541BP1.BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB.
In this way, constraint violations are only ignored for the BPM_TASK_INDEX_JOB
table.